# How do I turn on Safe Search ICS 4.0.4?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-search

I can't see any option to turn on Safe Search. Can anyone advice where I can find this?

Answer (score 2):

`System Settings->Select your Google account->Search->Near the bottom`.